# Getting ShareBeingDeleted error while updating protocol in azure storage share from SMB to NFS via Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In Terraform, Getting **ShareBeingDeleted** error while updating protocol in **azure storage share** from **SMB to NFS.** (Also for **NFS to SMB**)

I already deployed the azure storage share with SMB protocol using below source

```html
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "mystrgshr456"
  storage_account_name = "mystrgacnt456"
  quota                = 100
  enabled_protocol     = "SMB"
}
```

Now am planning to update the protocol from SMB to NFS. So have updated the source code as shown below.

```html
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "mystrgshr456"
  storage_account_name = "mystrgacnt456"
  quota                = 100
  enabled_protocol     = "NFS"
}
```

After changing source, ran the **terraform apply --auto-approve** command. And getting below error.

```html
$ terraform apply --auto-approve
azurerm_storage_share.example: Refreshing state... [id=https://mystrgacnt456.file.core.windows.net/mystrgshr456]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following
symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_storage_share.example must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
      ~ enabled_protocol     = "SMB" -> "NFS" # forces replacement
      ~ id                   = "https://mystrgacnt456.file.core.windows.net/mystrgshr456" -> (known after apply)
      ~ metadata             = {} -> (known after apply)
        name                 = "mystrgshr456"
      ~ resource_manager_id  = "/resourceGroups/tf-azure/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mystrgacnt456/fileServices/default/fileshares/mystrgshr456" -> (known after apply)
      ~ url                  = "https://mystrgacnt456.file.core.windows.net/mystrgshr456" -> (known after apply)
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - timeouts {}
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
azurerm_storage_share.example: Destroying... [id=https://mystrgacnt456.file.core.windows.net/mystrgshr456]
azurerm_storage_share.example: Destruction complete after 3s
azurerm_storage_share.example: Creating...
azurerm_storage_share.example: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_storage_share.example: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
azurerm_storage_share.example: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: creating Share "mystrgshr456" (Account "mystrgacnt456" / Resource Group "tf-azure"): shares.Client#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="ShareBeingDeleted" Message="The specified share is being deleted. Try operation later.\nRequestId:532d2678-b01a-00f4-4344-149210000000\nTime:2022-01-28T12:45:49.9175758Z"
│
│   with azurerm_storage_share.example,
│   on main.tf line 2, in resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example":
│    2: resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
│
╵
```

But storage share protocol has been successfully updated in azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

***This is a bug from ***`Terraform azurerm Provider`***  where The Storage Share recreation with updated protocol gives an error like :***

```
Error: creating Share "example" (Account "expstracc" / Resource Group "exap-rg"): shares.Client#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="ShareBeingDeleted" Message="The specified share is being deleted. Try operation later."
```

***Even though the Storage Share Protocol gets successfully updated and can be seen from Azure Portal.***

***This will be fixed in this ***[`Github Pull Request`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/15180)*** on the `azurerm_storage_share` .***